# Any Better Way to Set ListBox Width Equals to Column Width

Tags: excel, vba

i written following code. as i am new to vba. Can i get small version or alternative code to achieve the same result. i want to auto size column width with worksheet column used cells max length. i used dictionary method to store the max length of cells in a column and loop all the columns and store max length to dictionary.

```
'============Refresh ListBox===================
Public Function RefreshData()

Dim max As Integer
Dim Letter As String
Dim RngAddress As String
Dim C As Integer

'enable microsoft scripting runtime from tools ---> reference

Dim mydictionery As Scripting.Dictionary
Set mydictionery = New Scripting.Dictionary

C = 1
max = 0
Letter = "A"

For i = 1 To 26

RngAddress = Letter & 2 & ":" & Letter & 3

For Each cell In Range(RngAddress)
If Len(cell) > max Then max = Len(cell)
Next

mydictionery.Add Letter & max, 0 'add Letter & max to prevent duplicate key

max = 0 'reset max for next range
C = C + 1 'increase counter for dictionery
Letter = Chr(Asc(Letter) + 1) 'next column for range

Next i

Dim iRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Last_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("AB:AB"))

        With DataEntryFormDynamic.ListBox1


        .ColumnCount = 28
        .ColumnHeads = True

        .ColumnWidths = Mid(mydictionery.Keys(0), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(1), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(2), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(3), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(4), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(5), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(6), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(7), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(8), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(9), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(10), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(11), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(12), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(12), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(14), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(15), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(16), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(17), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(18), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(19), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(20), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(21), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(22), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(23), 2, 15) * 6 & "," _
                      & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(24), 2, 15) * 6 & "," & Mid(mydictionery.Keys(25), 2, 15) * 6 & ","

        If Last_Row = 1 Then
        .RowSource = "Database!A2:AB2"
        Else
        .RowSource = "Database!A2:AB" & Last_Row
        End If
        End With

Set mydictionery = Nothing
End Function


'in userform

Private Sub userform activate ()
Call RefreshData
end sub
```

Thank in advance for your help and support on this.

Comment: Please Note : i set monotype font "Courier New" for data worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one alternative:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    RefreshData
End Sub

Public Function RefreshData()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lRow As Long, rng As Range

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    lRow = Application.max(sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
    Set rng = sh.Range("A2:AB" & lRow)

    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 28
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = ColWidths(rng.Resize(2, rng.Columns.Count)) 'just using first 2 rows?
        .RowSource = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address()
    End With

End Function

Public Function ColWidths(rng As Range) As String
    Dim col As Range, arr(), i As Long, m
    ReDim arr(0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1)
    Debug.Print UBound(arr) + 1 & " columns"
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        m = rng.Parent.Evaluate("=Max(Len(" & rng.Columns(i).Address() & "))")
        If IsError(m) Then m = 1 'or some other suitable value on an error
        arr(i - 1) = m * 6
    Next i
    Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")
    ColWidths = Join(arr, ",")
End Function
```

Comment: I am getting error  on line ReDim arr(0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1)    'error 424 Object Required. can you please help me with placing code. i asted above code under module and called it on form activate. but it throws error 424 on run time. Thanks. it seems like too small code yet effective.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams ,  just tested your code. Still it encounter error 424 - object required on line . ==> ColumnCount = 28     . another error encountered with  == > with me.Listbox1 as invalid use of me,  i removed .me and it solved it but first error with line ColumnCount still exist. can you please check. thanks

Comment: Can i expect something like : you can set max columns width among two variants (i.e., Column Width, Column header text length) . example. if column width is max then set column width as column width else if column header text length  is max then set max width as column header text length. Thanks

Comment: I used Me when testing as all my code is in the form.  If you want some of the code outside of the form then you need to make sure it operatess on the correct instance of the form  - at least pass in the listbox control as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry. its working i replaced "with Me.ListBox1"   with  "with FormName.ListBox1"

Comment: Your codes are working fine as per my early request. can i expect some change in codes as per my above comments.

Comment: Why don't *you* try making the change you want, and post it as new question along with what you tried?

Comment: Thank you. i ll do the same. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The width of each column is put in an array and made into a single character, and applied to the list box.

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
        Dim sWidth As String
        Dim vR() As Variant
        Dim n As Integer

        Set rngDB = Range("a1:ab1")
        For Each rng In rngDB
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = rng.EntireColumn.Width
        Next rng
        sWidth = Join(vR, ";")
        Debug.Print sWidth
        With ListBox1
            .ColumnCount = 28
            .ColumnWidths = sWidth '<~~ 24;24;24;24;24;39;39;39;39;45;45;45;45;45;45;45;45;45;45;45;51;51;51;51;57;57;57;63
            .RowSource = "A1:AB2"
            .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        End With
    End Sub
```

**- What to resize to maximum**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim sWidth As String
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim myMax As Single

    Set rngDB = Range("a1:ab1")
    For Each rng In rngDB
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = rng.EntireColumn.Width
    Next rng
    myMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(vR)
    For i = 1 To n
        vR(i) = myMax
    Next i

    sWidth = Join(vR, ";")
    Debug.Print sWidth
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 28
        .ColumnWidths = sWidth '<~~ 63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63;63
        .RowSource = "A1:AB2"
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    End With
End Sub
```

### Image

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dy.Lee , Just tested your code. its working good so far. but can i expect something like : you can set max columns width among two variants (i.e., Column Width, Column header text length) . example. if column width is max then set column width as column width else if column header text length  is max then set max width as column header text length. Thanks

Comment: 1) I think there should be `.ColumnCount = n`. 2) you could improve the first code with `rngDB.EntireColumn.AutoFit` before starting to loop through `rngDB` 3)  you could dim  `vR` only once with `ReDim vR(1 To rnDB.Columns.Count)` before the loop

Comment: @HTH , i request you to please add your answer. thanks

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection, my suggestion was to improve what was already an answer. No need to steal from it

Comment: @HTH please give me code like you can set max columns width among two variants (i.e., Column Width, Column header text length) . example. if column width is max then set column width as column width else if column header text length is max then set max width as column header text length

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection,Your question is different from the original one. I need a point of clear question. The core of the question is still unclear.

Comment: Dear @Dy.Lee i want to auto size column width and show it in listbox as column header.. if text length in next row is more than column width than i want to show width of column =  text length else show auto fit column size. Hope it makes clear. please let me know if anything else you unclear? please see image of auto size https://ibb.co/Qmx04tp

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection,I have encountered the same thing before, and I know that there is such a function in vb, but there is no such function in Excel vba. I don't know if I'm wrong ...

Comment: @Dy.Lee can you make  a function like to compare column width with column max text length and display the max one among two.

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection, As HTH said, it seems that running my code after auto-aligning the columns in the excelsheet will give the same result.

Comment: @Dy.Le  if user manually align column width then i need to consider that also accordingly. that is why i am asking to compare and show accordingly on user form load which ever is max among column width and text length.

Comment: You have provided two codes i cannot use both at a time to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection,I'm giving some direction to your question, I'm not working with your data.
  Examination against the suggested advice is yours.

Comment: @Dy.Le I understand you suggestion. but i need help